# Start autofs on boot

Tags: 10.04, xubuntu, automount

I have `autofs` all setup, and it correctly mounts my shared directories.

However, right now, I have to manually run `sudo upstart autofs start` after every boot, before the automounting actually works.

I *think* in installed `autofs` manually through synaptic, though it has been a while. The computer in question is used as a lightweight server, and rarely gets restarted, so having to manually start a service isn't too big a deal, but my backups do not work until autofs is running, so I do worry.

Comment: I can't help directly, but I can confirm that `autofs` from the repositories is definitely auto-started on login/startup and will mount anything it sees in /etc/auto.master automatically.

Comment: @Scaine - Well, damn if I know what's going on, then. Maybe it was packaged into the xubuntu installation, and just not enabled until I set it up.

Comment: I'd do a re-install of autofs through synaptic, but getting it working at all was an enormous pain, and I don't know if a re-install would clobber my config files. Frankly, considering how much of a complete PITA it was to get working, I really don't want to to touch autofs itself, for fear of breaking it.

Comment: Most of the configuration for autofs is just `/etc/auto*.*`.  You'll have a master file, two or three scripts (auto.smb, auto.net and such like) and for each network share you'll have auto.smb.SERVERNAME or similar.  It *should* (grin) be relatively easy to back up, then restore!  Should be...

Comment: Anyone? This is still an issue for me....

Comment: What do you want to do with autofs exactly? If I understand correctly, it's a tool to mount stuff. Can't you do just do that with a new line in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @Exeleration-G - `autofs` automatically mounts shared directories on demand. It's better then just using `mount` because it does not hold connections to all your servers open all the time. It's a system service, so when you try to navigate to a directory a `autofs` manages, it mounts it for you. After the directory has been unused for a period of time, it unmounts it and closes the SMB (in this case) connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to `/etc/rc.local`

Using any editor:

Graphical

```
gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Command line

```
sudo -e /etc/rc.local
```

add / edit the following:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local 
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

service autofs start &

mount -a

exit 0
```

You could probably improve on that a bit, 4 60 second sleep are probably excessive, I would try one, and increase the number if needed.

Make it executable

```
sudo chmod u+x /etc/rc.local
```

Reboot and it should work. If not, try adding a sleep as per the bug report below.

See also [Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/autofs/+bug/40189)

Comment: I think the restarts may not be needed. All I have to do to get `autofs` to work normally is just issue a `sudo service autofs start`. The problem isn't that it's failing, it's that it is never starting. Anyways, I will try this when I get home from work later today.

Comment: I agree, the start ... sleep ... restart ... sleep ... seems excessive, probably written in frustration, but probably after a shorter script fails. Give it a try and you can of course optimize it for your needs.

Comment: Do you still need assistance ?

Comment: Nope, that did it. I just put `service autofs start` in rc.local, without any sleep or repetitions. I still wonder how I installed autofs without it bing set up to start, though.

Comment: Thank you for commenting back on the requirement for the sleep. I will revise my answer. As far as it not working out of the box, aye it is a bug. My guess would be autofs is running too soon, without waiting for some service to finish.